# Solr query searching on non-indexed fields

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Solr version 6.1.0

Created a schema with some fields as `indexed=true` on which I specifically want the solr main-query `q` to search.

And also added more fields, which I just wanted to select, so marked them as `stored=true` and `indexed=false`.

[image]

Issue now is that, main query `q=India` is searching on non-indexed fields like country, which I have specified in the image.

See the result below
[image]

It is selecting the non-indexed field only when I specify the full value of non-indexed field.

See result for `q=Indi`
[image]

How can I restrict solr from searching on non-index fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the screenshot above you're copying the content sent to the field `country` into the field `_text_`. When you're not giving Solr a specific field to search (i.e. you're not using one of the dismax handlers with `qf` or not prefixing your term with the field name `field:value`), it falls back to the default search field. This is set to `_text_` by default. This field is indexed, and since you're copying the content from your country field into the `_text_` field, the values from `country` will give a hit.

If you don't want this to happen, don't copy the content from `country` into `_text_`, or give Solr the actual field you want to search.

Comment: I have several fields (not all) on which I need to search the data, as per https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Common_field_options, the fields can be searchable on if it is marked as indexed=true, then when should I put my key which I want to search on indexed fields, I tried putting it in q (main query) and it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: As mentioned, you can use `qf` with the (e)dismax handlers (query fields - which fields to query. This allows you to weight the different fields separetly, giving more weight to one field over another - `qf=field1 field2^2` makes field2 twice as important as field1), or you can use a common field like in this case that you copy everything into, then search that field (like in `_text_` in your current schema). Or you can ask for a hit in a specific field using `q=field:value`.